# Is there any Sequence to apply morphological operations to a mask of an image? Are there any techniques to make boundaries smoother?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, image-segmentation

I am working on a project for Foreground vs Background separation (Salient object detection) and I need to create masks from my training images which have been segmented by a human. My images are either `PNG` with alpha channel or `JPG` with white background. The problem, is that when you see the images after creating masks, you find noise and very rough edges around the border. In order to smoothen the boundaries, I tried applying some  morphological operation. These are giving me better results than original for some images while reducing the noise. All I want to know is that what is the proper seqquence (if there is any) to apply morphological operations.

I have tried many variations for example

```
Erosion -> Blur
Blur -> Erosion
Blur -> Opening -> Closing
Opening -> Closing -> Blur
```

etc etc etc...

[Here is a dataset of more than 44K images](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/paramaggarwal/fashion-product-images-dataset)

```
def create_mask_from_image(image:[np.ndarray, Image.Image], morph:bool = True):
    '''
    Create a Black and White mask for a PNG Image OR an Image with Pure White Background
    '''
    if isinstance(image, Image.Image): image = np.array(image)
    
   
    if image.shape[-1] == 4: # RGBA Image
        image = np.array(Image.open('test.png'))
        mask = image[:,:,:3] # now the immage has Black Background
        non_black = np.any(mask != [0, 0, 0], axis=-1) # pixel which are Non-black AKS Foreground
        mask[non_black] = [255,255,255] # Make the foreground all white and background all black
        
    
    elif image.shape[-1] == 3: # RGB Image
        mask = image.copy()
        non_white = np.any(mask != [255, 255, 255], axis=-1) # pixel which are Non-White
        mask[non_white] = [0, 0, 0] # Set all the Non-white pixels to  black so object becomes black
        mask = np.bitwise_not(mask) # Black Background, Whitee Object
    

    if morph:
        # mask = cv2.medianBlur(mask, 5) # Blur
        # mask = cv2.blur(mask,(7,7))

        kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)

        mask = cv2.erode(mask, kernel) # erosion, reduce the portion of white inside black, removes the outer threads
        # mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel)

        mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (5,5), sigmaX = 2, sigmaY = 2, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT) # Blur

        # re-construct strictly binary image
        mask[mask < 127] = 0 
        mask [mask >= 127] = 255

    return mask
```

You can check the results as:

```
x = requests.get("https://storage.googleapis.com/kagglesdsdata/datasets/139630/329006/fashion-dataset/images/10019.jpg?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=gcp-kaggle-com%40kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20220524%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20220524T091345Z&X-Goog-Expires=259199&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=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").content

image = Image.open(BytesIO(x))

mask_without_morphological = Image.fromarray(create_mask_from_image(image, False),)
mask_with_morphological = Image.fromarray(create_mask_from_image(image, True),)
```

also, if there's someone experienced who has worked with these type of situations, which blurring technique would suit here. In my experiments, `cv2.blur` works better out of all.

You could open the image given below in case you're in a restricted environment.

[image]

Comment: It will be helpful if you can post a single image and it's corresponding mask for reference

Comment: I agree with Jeru. Paste one or a few images into the question. There's no way I'm going to download 44k images to help you with your question. :/

Comment: @JeruLuke With all due respect , did you, by chance, run the code which says **You can check the results as:**.

Comment: @Deshwal I am working in a restricted environment. I don't have access to those links. :)

Comment: @JeruLuke I have uploaded the image. You can get the mask by (in case my approach is coorrect) by using `Image.fromarray(create_mask_from_image(image, False),)`

Comment: @Deshwal +1 for carefully scripting the code which I executed. The result when `morph = True` looks smooth. While performing erosion you reduce the count of pixels by replacing them with black along the outer boundaries of the mask. I found it out using `np.count_nonzero()`. When using this mask later on it definitely will not hug the entire ROI properly. My suggestion: apply Gaussian filter directly on the mask, followed by threshold (0-126 :-> 0 & 127-255 :->255).

Comment: @Deshwal You would need to figure out the kernel size and standard deviation w.r.t to image size. The resulting mask would hug the ROI better. Again this is just my opinion. Really appreciate the care taken to frame the question.